# How to enable dragging for D3 elements overlaid on a leaflet map

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I've followed [Mike Bostock's tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) for rendering svg elements with D3 on top of a Leaflet map, but in addition to the functionality in his example I'd like for users to be able to reposition D3-rendered elements on the map by dragging them. That is, I want users to be able to geographically reposition objects in a D3-rendered SVG element in the leaflet-overlay-pane by dragging those elements, and have the updated geographic placements preserved when the user drags or zooms the Leaflet map.

With some very hacky html editing in the D3 drag events I've managed to do this ([see jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpo0a86x/1/) - drag the blue circles to confirm functionality) but I'm hoping to find a better method. Any suggestions? Here is what I have so far:

```
var svg, g, map, collection, transform, path, json, d_string;
json = get_json();
setup_map();

function setup_map(){
    map = L.map('map').fitBounds([[-3.82,-73.24],[-3.69,-73.35]]);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'OpenStreetMap, D3'
    }).addTo(map);  
    map.on("viewreset", reset);
    setup_d3();
}

function setup_d3(){
    svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg");
    g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

    drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

    transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint});
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

    g.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path");

    g.selectAll("path")
    .attr('fill','blue')
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .call(drag);
    reset();
}

function reset() {
    var buffer_space = 200; //so point markers are fully drawn, and to give you space to move markers around
    bounds = path.bounds(json);
    var topLeft = bounds[0], bottomRight = bounds[1];
    topLeft[0] -= buffer_space;
    topLeft[1] -= buffer_space;
    bottomRight[0] += buffer_space;
    bottomRight[1] += buffer_space;

    svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
      .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
      .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
      .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");
    g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
}

function projectPoint(x, y) {
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
    this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    d_string = d3.select(this).attr("d");
    d_string = d_string.substring(d_string.indexOf("m"));
}

function dragged(d) {
    var offset = get_leaflet_offset();
    var size = d3.select(this).attr("r")/2;
    var pt = [d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX - size - offset[0], d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY - size - offset[1]];
    var hackpath = "M" + pt[0] + "," + pt[1] + d_string;
    d3.select(this).attr("d", hackpath);
}

function dragended(d) {
    var offset = get_leaflet_offset();
    var size = d3.select(this).attr("r")/2;
    var pt = layer_to_LL(d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX - size - offset[0], d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY - size - offset[1]);
    d.geometry.coordinates = [pt.lng, pt.lat];
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
    reset();
}

function get_leaflet_offset(){
    var trfm = $(".leaflet-map-pane").css('transform');
    trfm = trfm.split(", ");
    return [parseInt(trfm[4]), parseInt(trfm[5])];
}

function layer_to_LL(x,y){return map.layerPointToLatLng(new L.Point(x,y));}

function projectPoint(x, y) {
  var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
  this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}

function projectSinglePoint(x, y) {
  var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
  console.log(point);
  return point;
}

function get_json(){
    return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269"}
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"id": "pt0"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.25, -3.72]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"id": "pt1"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.37, -3.82]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {"id": "pt2"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.32, -3.67]
        }
    }]
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I would have used the default leaflet option to make `markers` and set it as `draggable`

Something like this:

```
  json.features.forEach(function(d) {
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(d.geometry.coordinates[1], d.geometry.coordinates[0]), {
        draggable: true
    });
    marker.addTo(map);
  })
```

This will relieve you of doing the dragging logic on D3 you can see how much code got reduced :)

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/yjso8kqf/)

Marker documentation [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Cyril. This doesn't answer the question asked, but it's a very useful alternative!